# TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object when updating document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an existing document by increment a counter and pushing an object to an array.

Here's the schema for User:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  [...]
  posts: {
    totalWords: { type: Number, min: 0, default: 0 },
    _entries: [
      {
        words: { type: Number, min: 0 },
        body: { type: String },
        date: Date
      }
    ]
  },
});
```

And here's the update code:

```
var newPost = {
  words: req.body.words,
  body: req.body.entry,
  date: new Date()
};

User.findOne(req.user._id, function (err, user) {
  var previous = user.posts.totalWords;
  user.posts.totalWords = previous + newPost.words;
  user.posts._entries.push(newPost);

  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return res.send(400, err);
    return res.json(newPost);
  });
});
```

I get the following error:

```
[TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering my own question**

I was able to solve the problem by changing:

```
User.findOne(req.user._id, function (err, user) { [...] });
```

Into this:

```
User.findById(req.user._id, function (err, user) { [...] });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, if you would like to use findOne you need follow syntax:

User.findOne({'_id': req.user._id}, {}, function (err, user) {
  ...
  });

Comment: This is the correct response. Currently there's a bug in the latest release (marked as fixed though) where they don't properly handle passing null for the fields property

Comment: You can pass an empty object, or modify line 175 of collection.js to add the check

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `findById()` vs. `findOne()`, but I've had problems with Mongoose objects returning `Object.keys called on non-object` while saving or updating with mal-formed data or data corresponding to an older schema. While initializing the document, Mongoose was expecting a subdocument of some kind, but the data in the database didn't match that.

For me it usually happens when I change schemas from a simple object (`String`, `Number`, etc.) to a more complex subdocument of some kind. The schema types are mixed up and the object won't load, not even to fix the problem. I had to go into my database using [the native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/), search for mal-formed documents using the `$type` operator, and update them individually.