# Node & Mongoose - Error on save: TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In the below user schema there is a `foobar.events` field, that I am trying to push new hashes (that are received from an API POST request) to.

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    foobar: {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String,
        events       : [{
            action          : String,
            timestamp       : Date,
            user_xid        : String,
            type            : {type: String},
            event_xid       : String    
        }]
    }

});
```

And here is the logic for that Express route:

```
app.post('/foobar/post', function(req, res) {
    var jb_user_xid  = req.body['events'][0]['user_xid'];
    var jb_timestamp = req.body['events'][0]['timestamp'];
    var jb_action    = req.body['events'][0]['action'];
    var jb_type      = req.body['events'][0]['type'];
    var jb_event_xid = req.body['events'][0]['event_xid'];

    User.findOne({'foobar.id':jb_user_xid}, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        user.foobar.events.push({
            user_xid: jb_user_xid,
            timestamp: jb_timestamp,
            action: jb_action,
            type: jb_type,
            event_xid: jb_event_xid
        });
        user.save(function(err) {
            if (err){ 
                console.log("Error on save: " + err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Save successful");
            }
        });
    });

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
    return;
});
```

The `find` method is executed successfully, but the following error is thrown when trying to save to the database: `Error on save: TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object` - any idea why this error is being thrown?

[This thread had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22253665/typeerror-object-keys-called-on-non-object-when-updating-document), but changing the `findOne` to `findById` broke my user query.

As a side note, this is what is returned in `req.body` from the API:

```
{  events:
    [ { action: 'updation',
        timestamp: 1408846680,
        user_xid: 'aguxwNqb_Xg87buMyP6Wiw',
        type: 'move',
        event_xid: 'vhAkgg1XwQvLynAkkCc8Iw' } ],
   notification_timestamp: 1408846680 }
```

And here is what's returned from the `User.findOne` method

```
{ __v: 17,
   _id: 53f7d23e432de20200970c10,
   foobar:
    { id: 'aguxwNqb_Xg87buMyP6Wiw',
      name: 'Test User',
      token: 'W3AjaI7_iOWilcKRpmxenQWi',
      events: [] }
}
```

Comment: How did `findById` break the user query? The error looks like the `user` variable's value does not have the correct type. What does `user` look like when it is logged?

Comment: The `user_xid` field links to a specific user, that's why the `findOne` method is used. I've updated the question to include the `user` log

Comment: It could be a problem with your schema. The line that says `type: {type: String}` should probably be something like `event_type: String`. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the issue, it just looks odd to me.

Comment: @ctlacko The API response includes a field named `type`, which is a reserved named in Mongoose. Thus, I have to manually override the `type` with that syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error was actually due to old data within my Mongo database. The `events` field was full of extra strings. I deleted these and my original code began working successfully. No changes to the above code were necessary.

Comment: I had this same error and it was because I had a field defined as a custom subschema of Object Ids, but data in this field already contained arrays of strings (that looked like Object Ids).  Queries were written to look for strings so they continued to work.  Updates would not because Mongo could not run Object.keys() on this subschema that was in fact an array of strings.  Lesson:  Make sure your schema matches your existing data!

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works perfectly.. for me.. try to check mongoose module version or something.if u have still problem please do it using update function rather than save..It would be more performance oriented.

this is the following i used

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback () {
      // yay!
    });
    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

        foobar: {
            id           : String,
            name         : String,
            events       : [{
                action          : String,
                timestamp       : Date,
                user_xid        : String,
                type            : {type: String},
                event_xid       : String    
            }]
        }

    });







    var User =  mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

    /*
    //used for saving.
    var person =  new User({  foobar:
        { id: 'aguxwNqb_Xg87buMyP6Wiw',
          name: 'Test User',
          token: 'W3AjaI7_iOWilcKRpmxenQWi',
          events: [] }
    });
    person.save(function(err,data){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);
    })

    */


    User.findOne({'foobar.id':'aguxwNqb_Xg87buMyP6Wiw'}, function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            user.foobar.events.push({ action: 'updation',
            timestamp : 1408846680,
            user_xid: 'aguxwNqb_Xg87buMyP6Wiw',
            type: 'move',
            event_xid: 'vhAkgg1XwQvLynAkkCc8Iw' });
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err){ 
                    console.log("Error on save: " + err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Save successful");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! I will heed your warning for using `update` rather than `save`